# Dotnet watch run - Force reload on "rude edit" - .Net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, dotnet-cli, dotnet-watch

I run web projects like this, during development:

```
dotnet watch run
```

The project/browser reloads when I make a change. Awesome!

However, sometimes I will be shown this:

```
Unable to apply hot reload because of a rude edit.
Do you want to restart your app - Yes (y) / No (n) / Always (a) / Never (v)?
```

Is there something I can add to the commandline, so I force the **Always (a)** option?

Something like this:

```
dotnet watch run --AlwaysRestartOnRudeEdit
```

According to my google-fu/duckduck-fu, such an option does not exist - but I would like it confirmed. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not yet. A feature like that has been merged into the .NET 6.0.2 update. Once released, it will be possible to force this behavior by setting an environment variable named `DOTNET_WATCH_RESTART_ON_RUDE_EDIT` to `true`.

Source: [aspnetcore issue #37190](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37190)

Until then, user `eknkc` [posted](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37023#issuecomment-927346575) a possible workaround (Unix):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn dotnet watch run
expect  "Do you want to restart your app - Yes (y) / No (n) / Always (a) / Never (v)?\r"
send -- "a"
expect eof
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552641/10565375 is much simpler

Answer (score 3):

Try this [option](https://dotnet%20watch%20--non-interactive) for `dotnet watch` (from .NET 7 onwards)

```
dotnet watch --non-interactive
```

From `dotnet watch --help`:

```
--non-interactive Runs dotnet-watch in non-interactive mode. 
This option is only supported when running with Hot Reload enabled. 
Use this option to prevent console input from being captured.
```

It will restart when a rude edit occurs:

> dotnet watch ⌚ Unable to apply hot reload because of a rude edit.
> dotnet watch ⌚ Exited dotnet watch
>  Building...

Answer (score 2):

Create an environment variable `DOTNET_WATCH_RESTART_ON_RUDE_EDIT` set to `true`. The run `dotnet watch` like normal.

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure you restart your terminal after adding the environment variable (and if you started the terminal from Visual Studio, you need to restart Visual Studio as well)

Comment: Here's the environmental variables section from the docs for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch#environment-variables