# Dotnet CLI Hot Reload: always restart app on rude edits?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnet-cli, hot-reload

When using [Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/hot-reload?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-cli) in the .NET CLI...

```
$ dotnet watch
watch : Hot reload enabled. For a list of supported edits, see https://aka.ms/dotnet/hot-reload. Press "Ctrl + R" to restart.
watch : Building...
  ...
watch : Started
```

... any rude edit leads to the following prompt:

```
watch : Unable to apply hot reload because of a rude edit.
watch : Do you want to restart your app - Yes (y) / No (n) / Always (a) / Never (v)?
```

Is there any way to tell the CLI to default to "Always"? Something like `dotnet watch --always-restart`?

(asking because I'd like to run `dotnet watch` in a container)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it turns out, [yes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38798)!

```
$ export DOTNET_WATCH_RESTART_ON_RUDE_EDIT=1
$ dotnet watch
```

(.NET 6.0.2+)

Comment: Huh, this doesn't appear to work if I `set DOTNET_WATCH_RESTART_ON_RUDE_EDIT=1` in windows. I at least have option to say always-reload, but I can't get the default behavior of my `dotnet watch` to be always-reload. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? My machine doesn't have an `export` cmd (win11 cmder/cmd).

Comment: What SDK version are you using?

Comment: `dotnet --version` gives me `6.0.200`

Comment: Try [7.0.100-preview.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0)? Maybe it didn't actually get backported to 6.0.2 for some reason.

Comment: Ah, I found a clue. I was running as npm script that set the env var and then ran dotnet watch. If I do those commands directly, it works as expected. Will see if I can get it to work as one tidy little npm script somehow...

Comment: Yay, using `cross-env` npm package worked like so: `cross-env DOTNET_WATCH_RESTART_ON_RUDE_EDIT=1 dotnet watch`. Note it's important to not have `&&` between setting the var and starting dotnet watch. Seems like dotnet could maybe account for that though, since it seems webpack is able to find it if I put an && between and use normal `set` command.

Comment: Oh, and I confirmed same issue on preview 7, fwiw.

Comment: Ok cool, so it worked with the 6.0.200 SDK, correct?

Comment: Correct, I downgraded back to 6.0.200 after figuring that out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77524900/10565375 is much simpler

Answer (score 8):

It is also possible to pass the non interactive flag:

```
dotnet watch run --non-interactive
```

`--non-interactive`

Runs dotnet watch in non-interactive mode. Use this option to prevent console input from being requested. When hot reload is enabled and a rude edit is detected, dotnet watch restarts the app. Available since .NET 7 SDK.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch#options
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552641/10565375